# How to specify semi colon character ';' as a line ending character when importing CSV to Excel on Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, csv, import, newlines

(Using Microsoft Excel form Mac version 15.18)

Can see delimiters for the columns in the import steps, but no-where is there an option for defining what the line ending character is.

I need this so that I can output a CSV all on one line for a log output but with semi colons to mark where the line endings are.

Comment: And where would you specify them number of fields that have been processed, Tyson?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Excel, you need to replace `;` to newline in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality only exists in the Windows version.  On the Mac, you either have to do some upfront text manipulation or open the CSV file using the OpenOffice or LibreOffice spreadsheet application.  These applications have a full-featured import dialog that opens when you read a CSV file.  You can specify any delimiter character which you like.  Then you can save the file in the .xlsm format and open it in Excel for Mac.